# How to find suitable inner rails for a used server?

Tags: rackmount

I have a old server rack which I got from the scrapyard and it only had the inner rails 364996 and a 2nd part number that I cannot recall. The seller had absolutely no idea what he's selling so he couldn't tell me what inner rails I need.

I tried searching for inner rails on ebay and I got several results 533877-001, 365002-002, 65016-001 and I have no idea which ones will fit. which is the appropriate part or what is appropriate in the first place.

All I know is the outer rails I have are approximately 650mm deep (from bracket to bracket).

Answer (score 2):

Scour every inch of the rack. Follow up on every part number.

Take a picture of the rack. Every angle. Post it to forums like this.

Answer (score 0):

Rail kits are for servers, not for racks.   A standard 19" rack will take almost any server rackmount rails, providing the rack is deep enough.

For really old kit, mind out for round holes instead of square ones.  HP had round holes in their racks for years, to be difficult, and mounting square cagenuts in round holes is a challenge.

`364996` is part of a rail kit for a HP DL360 gen4 through gen7, and it is only useful on that hardware without modification.  Without one of those hosts, its not much use to you unless you custom-make a wooden shelf/drawer to sit between the rails and hold stuff.